# setInterval: changing numbers in function depending on times that event has occured

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I need to figure out how to use setInterval() to make text increase 1px(font-size) every 1000 ms. Here's my setup:

```
    function boom() {
  var fwuff = document.getElementById("fwuff");
  fwuff.style.display="block";
  fwuff.style.textAlign="center"
  setInterval(function(){
    fwuff.style.fontSize=??
  }, 1000);
}
```

What I don't know is what to put in the fwuff.style.fontSize so I can get the size to increase every time the event occurs. Does anyone understand and know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks Karl! Works awesomely! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a variable :

```
function boom() {
    var fwuff = document.getElementById("fwuff");
    var myAwesomeVar = 10; //Base font size
    fwuff.style.display="block";
    fwuff.style.textAlign="center"
    setInterval(function(){
        fwuff.style.fontSize= myAwesomeVar + "px";
        myAwesomeVar++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your variable name makes me want to vomit, I've seen entire books (e.g. on AngularJS) filled with *awesome* this or *awesome* that.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Well, that's not my problem if it make you vomit! As for myself, i've never read anything about angular and it's more a reference to egoraptor *Awesome serie*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a global variable or get the current `fontSize` in order to change it. Using a global variable will be slightly more efficient, however if you do not know the size of the font you are changing, you can use the `fontSize` of the element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tBFv/1/)

Getting then setting the `fontSize`:

```
function boom() {
    var fwuff = document.getElementById("fwuff");
    var myAwesomeVar = 10; //Base font size
    fwuff.style.display="block";
    fwuff.style.textAlign="center";
    setInterval(function(){
       curFontSize = $('#fwuff').css('fontSize');
       FontSizeNumber = parseInt(curFontSize);
       newFontSizeNumber = FontSizeNumber + 1 + 'px';
       $('#fwuff').css('fontSize', newFontSizeNumber);
    }, 1000);
}
```

or alternatively, you could use a variable:

```
function boom() {
        var fwuff = document.getElementById("fwuff");
        var myAwesomeVar = 10; //Base font size
        fwuff.style.display="block";
        fwuff.style.textAlign="center";
        fontSizeVar = 12;
        setInterval(function(){
           fontSizeVar++;
           newFontSizeVal = fontSizeVar + 'px';
           $('#fwuff').css('fontSize', newFontSizeVal);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Note: the question was tagged jquery. If this was accidental and you want me to convert to traditional JS, just ask.